# How to access the 'neighbors' property of nodes in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I am building a graph with `react-force-graph-2d` and have the following snippet from an example:

```
 const data2 = useMemo(() => {
        const gData = genRandomTree(80);

        // cross-link node objects
        gData.links.forEach((link) => {
          const a = gData.nodes[link.source];
          const b = gData.nodes[link.target];
          !a.neighbors && (a.neighbors = []);
          !b.neighbors && (b.neighbors = []);
          a.neighbors.push(b);
          b.neighbors.push(a);

          !a.links && (a.links = []);
          !b.links && (b.links = []);
          a.links.push(link);
          b.links.push(link);
        });

        return gData;
      }, []);
```

All references to `neighbors` and `links` show errors, with the message "*Property 'neighbors' does not exist on type '{ id: any; }'.*" and "*Property 'links' does not exist on type '{ id: any; }'.*" respectively.

I've tried defining types with said properties but this doesn't change anything:

```
type gDataNodeType = {
id: any;
neighbors: any[];
links: any[];
}
```

after which I change const `a` and `b` to:

```
const a:gDataNodeType = gData.nodes[link.source];
const b:gDataNodeType = gData.nodes[link.target];
```

but then I get the error:

> Type '{ id: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'gDataNodeType': neighbors, links

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

Here is the function for GetRandomTree:

```
export function genRandomTree(N = 300, reverse = false) {
  return {
    nodes: [...Array(N).keys()].map(i => ({ id: i })),
      links: [...Array(N).keys()]
    .filter(id => id)
    .map(id => ({
      [reverse ? 'target' : 'source']: id,
      [reverse ? 'source' : 'target']: Math.round(Math.random() * (id-1))
    }))
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you share the data type of `genRandomTree`?

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza done.

Answer (score 0):

The properties **links** and **neighbors** are not declared.
You can declare and initialize them in the genRadomTree function:

```
export function genRandomTree(N = 300, reverse = false) {
  return {
    nodes: [...Array(N).keys()].map(i => (
         {id: i, neighbors: [] as number[], links: [] as number[]})),
    links: [...Array(N).keys()]
    .filter(id => id)
    .map(id => ({
      [reverse ? 'target' : 'source']: id,
      [reverse ? 'source' : 'target']: Math.round(Math.random() * (id-1))
    }))
  };
}
```

And then you can delete those two lines because those properties are already initialized

```
!a.neighbors && (a.neighbors = []);
!b.neighbors && (b.neighbors = []);
```